# Netty ChannelPromise exctionCaught

Tags: java, exception, netty, promise, codec

I'm writing a codec for netty but I have some problems with handling exceptions in the encocde case.

From the API I can see `exceptionCaught(..)` will be deprecated in the future.
Instead the channel promise must fail.

Dose anyone knows an source code example for that? What needs to be done in the encode method of my codec to make the promise fail?

http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelHandler.html

`exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause)`
Deprecated. 
Will be removed in the future and only `ChannelInboundHandler` will receive `exceptionCaught` events. For `ChannelOutboundHandler` the `ChannelPromise` must be failed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the problem is ... Just call ChannelPromise.setFailure(...) and you are good